# Reversing a multi-value hash in perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
{ bmw      => { id => 1, color => brown } }
{ mercedes => { id => 2, color => black } }
```

I want to reverse this hash in perl so that I just get a mapping of id => name_of_car. Do I need to use the reverse function somehow?

Note: I can always iterate through the original hash and assign the keys and values accordingly in the new hash, nut I wanted to know if there was a slicker way.

Comment: I think you should accept one of our answers.  How can you get slicker than Kinopiko's one liner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't need a slick way:

```
my %h = (
    bmw      => { id => 1, color => "brown" } ,
    mercedes => { id => 2, color => "black" } 
);
my %j = map { ($h{$_}{id} => $_) } keys %h;

for (keys %j) {
    print "$_ $j{$_}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./silly.pl 
1 bmw
2 mercedes
```

Comment: Hey, no need to be down on your solution.  Your way looks pretty slick to me :).

Comment: This is just the usual way though.

Comment: I see that we have different definitions of "slick"

Answer (score 2):

What you've posted is not valid perl, but I think I take your meaning.  One slick way to do this would be with a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) and a map.

```
my %hash = (
    bmw      => { id => 1, color => 'brown' },
    mercedes => { id => 2, color => 'black' },
);
my %new_hash;
@new_hash{ map { $_->{id} } values %hash } = keys %hash;
```

Comment: Why is an alias (@) symbol used on the last line before new_hash?

Comment: @syker: please look at the link masonk provided about "hash slice".

Comment: This is special syntax for a hash slice (linked above).  You provide a list of keys on the left hand side and a list of values on the right hand side.  Perl guarantees that the order in which values %hash are returned is the same order as that in which keys %hash are returned, so this works.